# I am trying to update data in my app but while I push after clicking into onEdit function, I am not able to display component which is linked below

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, antd

The file where I have performed route

```
    const { url } = useRouteMatch();
   <Switch>
     <PrivateRoute exact path={`${url}/userlist`}><UserList/></PrivateRoute>
     <Route exact path={`${url}/useredit/:id`} component={UpdateUser}/>
     <PrivateRoute exact path={`${url}/property`}><PropertyData/></PrivateRoute>
     <PrivateRoute exact path={`${url}/publish`}><PublishData/></PrivateRoute>
     <PrivateRoute exact path={`${url}/orderdata`}><OrderData/></PrivateRoute>
     <PrivateRoute exact path={`${url}/ordernow`}><OrderNow/></PrivateRoute>
     <PrivateRoute exact path={`${url}/orderedit/:id`}><UpdateOrder/></PrivateRoute>
     <PrivateRoute exact path={`${url}/statusedit/:id`}><UpdateStatus/></PrivateRoute>
   </Switch>
```

I am not being able to route from the following file

```
 function onEdit(userdata: any) {
    dispatch({type: ActionType.setUserList, payload: userdata });
    history.push(`${url}/useredit/${userdata.id}`)
    console.log(url);
```

I'm trying to update something but while I push to  {`${url}/useredit/${userdata.id}`} which is linked with <Route exact path={`${url}/useredit/:id`} component={UpdateUser}/> but i am not able to link the component!

Comment: Is pushing into the array really correct way to update? Aren't you just creating duplicates? and your `:id` in the Switch element is inside a string. So it is literally looking for a path ending in `:id`. Try putting it outside and into `[ ]`.

Comment: can you just write down the code please?

Comment: in fact, if i  use history.push(`${url}/useredit) and inside switch <Route exact path={`${url}/useredit`} component={UpdateUser}/>, it  will still not work

Comment: I need more of your code if you want me to give you an exact answere.. where do you create the 'history' array and what does it contain before and after the call of the onEdit function?

Comment: it's large amount of code so can we add on social media please?

Comment: and it's not `${url}/useredit` but `${url}/useredit/`['id'] .. though you need the value of 'id' and if you pass an url object throught the dispatcher anyway, why complicate with the template literal? just do `url.userEdit = `${ url }/useredit/${ userdata.id }`` and then in the switch: `<Route exact path={ url.userEdit } component={UpdateUser}/>`

Comment: http://zergski.com/tmp.txt <- fb for messenger

Comment: you are not gettingmebro, useredit must be string

Comment: it is... if you get the value from an object that was defined as a sting, it will be a string..

Comment: I have sent you a friend request, accept the request